Pandas get first negative number from the bottom
I have following df. In which I want to see the first negative number after the last outcome number. & in the "first negative from last " col "this should occur or rather anything to highlight that row. The "this should appear on the first negative after the last outcome number (outcome number can be postive or negative & "this should appear only against negative rice number & not the positive rice number).
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1=pd.DataFrame({
        "rice": [49235.6,-49234.5,-49230.05,-49190.2,49193.1,-49140.95,-49125.3],
        "outcome": [-68.8499999999985,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,-41.4000000000014,np.nan,np.nan,],
        "first negative from last ": [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,"this",np.nan],
       })

I was trying to use
df.shit()

but not sure how to put conditions.
For better understanding following 2 df had shown exactly in which row "this" would appear.
df2=pd.DataFrame({
        "rice": [49235.6,-49234.5,-49230.05,-49190.2,49193.1,49140.95,-49125.3],
        "outcome": [-68.8499999999985,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,56,np.nan,np.nan,],
        "first negative from last ": [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,"this"],
       })




df3=pd.DataFrame({
        "rice": [49235.6,49234.5,-49230.05,-49190.2,-49193.1,-49140.95,-49125.3],
        "outcome": [6.8499999999985,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,],
        "first negative from last ": [np.nan,np.nan,"this",np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
       })


Code
import numpy as np
cond = (df1['outcome'].bfill().isna() & df1['rice'].lt(0))
df1['first negative from last'] = (
    np.where(cond & (df1.index == cond.idxmax()), 'this', None)
)

df1:
       rice  outcome first negative from last
0  49235.60   -68.85                     None
1 -49234.50      NaN                     None
2 -49230.05      NaN                     None
3 -49190.20      NaN                     None
4  49193.10   -41.40                     None
5 -49140.95      NaN                     this
6 -49125.30      NaN                     None


You could build masks to identify the region on interest (after last non-NA and negative), then get the first match (if any) with idxmax:
# mask to get values after last outcome
m1 = df1.loc[::-1, 'outcome'].isna().cummin()
# mask to get negative numbers
m2 = df1['rice'].lt(0)

s = df1.loc[m1&m2, 'rice'].isna()
if not s.empty:
    df1.loc[s.idxmax(), 'first negative from last'] = 'this'

Alternatively, using shift:
m = df1['outcome'].notna()
df1['first negative from last'] = (
    m.map({True: 'this'}).shift().mask(m[::-1].cummax())
)

Output:
       rice  outcome first negative from last
0  49235.60   -68.85                      NaN
1 -49234.50      NaN                      NaN
2 -49230.05      NaN                      NaN
3 -49190.20      NaN                      NaN
4  49193.10   -41.40                      NaN
5 -49140.95      NaN                     this
6 -49125.30      NaN                      NaN

Intermediates (first approach):
       rice  outcome     m1     m2  m1&m2 first negative from last
0  49235.60   -68.85  False  False  False                      NaN
1 -49234.50      NaN  False   True  False                      NaN
2 -49230.05      NaN  False   True  False                      NaN
3 -49190.20      NaN  False   True  False                      NaN
4  49193.10   -41.40  False  False  False                      NaN
5 -49140.95      NaN   True   True   True                     this
6 -49125.30      NaN   True   True   True                      NaN

Intermediates (second approach):
       rice  outcome      m   map shift  cummax first negative from last
0  49235.60   -68.85   True  this  None    True                      NaN
1 -49234.50      NaN  False   NaN  this    True                      NaN
2 -49230.05      NaN  False   NaN   NaN    True                      NaN
3 -49190.20      NaN  False   NaN   NaN    True                      NaN
4  49193.10   -41.40   True  this   NaN    True                      NaN
5 -49140.95      NaN  False   NaN  this   False                     this
6 -49125.30      NaN  False   NaN   NaN   False                      NaN

